# .NET MVC 5 How can I route a URI with an integer parameter only to /Home/Index?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an web app that I need to route a URL like:
    http://example.com/1234567890
to the standard 'Home' Controller and 'Index' Action (/Home/Index).

An I just put another MapRoute in the RouteConfig Module? -- something like:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name:="Clients",
        url:="{tendigits:int}",
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    )
```

Obviously the above doesn't seem to work, hence the reason for my question. Thanks in advance! (VB.NET 4.6)

**EDIT:**

I get 404's with the above. Changes such as the following STILL render 404's:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        name:="Clients",
        url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = "\d(10)"}
    )
```

**EDIT #2**
This is the entire code of the Route.Config file:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Mvc
Imports System.Web.Routing

Public Module RouteConfig
Public Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes    'added

    routes.MapRoute(
        name:="Clients",
        url:="{tendigits}",
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index"},
        constraints:=New With {.tendigits = "\\d{10}"}
    )

    routes.MapRoute(
        name:="Default",
        url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    )

End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace line `url:="{tendigits:int}"` with `url:="{id}"`every thing else looks fine.

Comment: Thank you @Sandip Patel for your reply. I tried it with and without the :int constrainer (which I need to do) but it didn't work - at least not with localhost, but I don't think that would matter. Any other ideas?

Comment: @HumbleBeginnings, please try below code
`routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Clients",
                url: "{tendigits}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
                constraints: new { tendigits = "\\d{10}" }
            );`
It has to pass 10 digits otherwise will give 404

Comment: no luck. here's my VB equivalent -- am I missing something?
            `routes.MapRoute(
            name:="Clients",
            url:="{tendigits}",
            defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index"},
            constraints:=New With {.tendigits = "\\d{10}"}
        )`
I thought that there was only one "\" necessary but maybe I am wrong...

Comment: I am putting it above the default which I believe is correct. The regular processing falls through this new route appropriately, but I still get 404's on 10 digits.

Comment: @HumbleBeginnings you are right its not working in vb.net. but some how working in c#. I have alternate plan for that. Comment route="Clients" from RouteConfig. And add route attribute at Action in Controller as below. I tested it in vb project and its working fine.

    `<Route("{tendigits:regex(^\d{10}$)}")>
    Function Index(ByVal tendigits As Integer) As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function`

Comment: Thank you but I had preferred NOT to use it at the controller level for logic reasons. There must be a reason. It seems very strange for it to be working in C# and not VB. Thanks for your persistence with this.

Answer (score 0):

On a whim, I decided to try another syntax which has proved to be successful (at least so far):

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name:="Clients",
        url:="{tendigits}",
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .tendigits = ""},
        constraints:=New With {.tendigits = "\d{10}"}
    )
```

If anyone sees anything wrong with this approach that I may be missing, please advise.